# Flask-migrate makes SQLite migration instead of PSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

Hi I've exported in virtualenv database with command

```
export DATABASE_URL="postgresql://localhost/dbname"
```

But after running

```
python manage.py init
```

and

```
python manage.py db migrate
```

Result is:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
```

PostreSQL database have been previously created and SQLAlchemy URI have been set in config.py file. During migration i have opened psql db in another terminal window (in the venv) with commands

```
psql
```

and then

```
\c dbname
```

How can I connect to the PSQL db?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the correct connection string. The format is

`dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database`

So yours should be

`postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/dbname`

Source: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#database-urls